# How can I draw this commutative diagram?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams, arrow-curve

Here is the diagram I want to draw:

[image]

Any

Comment: Try with `tikz-cd`.

Comment: @Zarko could you tell me some more details please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just sit down and read the manual of `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
   \arrow[r,"c_*"]
   \arrow[dr,bend right,"\Delta"'] &
H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X\vee\Sigma X)
  \arrow[r,"(f\vee g)_*"]
  \arrow[d,shift right=0.5em,"j?"'] &
H_{\bullet}(Y) \\
& H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)\oplus H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,shift right=0.5em,"i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}"']
  \arrow[ur,bend right,"f_*\oplus g_*"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's examine one of the arrows

```
\arrow[dr,bend right,"\Delta"']
```

We want it to go down and right, with a bend to the right (the logic about the direction is not immediate), with a label `\Delta` on the right side of the arrow (denoted by the prime).

Right and left are determined like for rivers: imagine to be at the source and to be looking towards the end.